# data schema style, should the 'name' of an object be the key or a property

Tags: javascript, database, api-design

I have had some trouble finding online advice on this topic, although I have had to make the choice several times in API design.

Should a set of data be presented in a mapping, or an array (with the 'name' of each node as a property)?

mapping:

```
{ "data_name": {"data_value": 10, "unit": "bytes"} }
```

array:

```
[ {"name": "data_name" "data_value": 10, "unit": "bytes"} ]
```

The mapping approach certainly makes data creation and reading easier, fewer lines of code. However the array approach creates a nicely encapsulated type, suitable for providing to a constructor or function as a single variable instead of a (name, data_type) pair of variables. The array approach also seems to correspond more closely to a database style, where the 'name' would likely be some named field.

Of course the array approach can be trivially converted into a mapping;

```
mapping = dict((v['name'],v) for v in array)
```

Converting from the mapping to an array requires changing the datatype (by introducing a new property, 'name'). The array -> mapping conversion also allows choice to the user of the key, eg a UUID, hash, or any paramater.

The google style guide did not weigh in sadly: http://google.github.io/styleguide/jsoncstyleguide.xml

Things seem in favour of the array approach, but it does tend to require more code, and sometimes seems unnatural at first.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt at an answer after a few more days discussion.

In a nutshell, always choose the array format. Here are the situations where choosing the mapping makes sense:

1. You are hacking or writing a one off. - saving one line of code is worth it
2. There is a very obvious choice of the key, and it is never needed as a property of the data.

The benefit of the array is that the data points exist as a single unit, there is no pair of keys and data.